# Are there any measure of overlap of two wave functions other than inner product?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

The similarity of two wave functions is usually measured by the inner product $\langle \psi_1 | \psi_2 \rangle$.

There is a fancier way to measure distance between two density operators, namely, [Bures metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bures_metric).

Are there any other metrics to measure wave function distances?

Comment: [probably related](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Norms_on_inner_product_spaces).

Comment: Thanks! There are numerous ways to define inner product, but do they have physical significance?